# Add text value in another text in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i am making correct spelling app for kids where i need this when i click on given option it will be add in top text in order

my try

```
Center(
                                                        child: Text(
                              imageList[anu1].wrongSpell1,
                            ),
                          ),
```

i want to add this text value to another . when click on this text it would be add in variable

```
  var mytext;
```

i add my text in this variable like this

```
  mytext = mytext.add(imageList[anu1].wrongSpell1);
                         setState(() {});
```

here i show my added text

```
Text(
                    mytext.toString(),
                  )
```

Comment: where is your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is "concatenate" strings.

```
String mytext = 'starting text';


TextButton(
  onPressed: ()  {
     setState(() {
     mytext = mytext + imageList[anu1].wrongSpell1;
    });
  
  },
   child: Text(imageList[anu1].wrongSpell1),
  )

                        
//// here is where you would show your text:
Text(mytext)
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is:

```
String myname = 'ottoman';
setState(() {
     myname = myname + imageList[anu1].wrongSpell1;
});
```